# Mosfet Amplifier design help

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, design, gain, input

I am currently designing a MOSFET common source amplifier for my electronics lab class. My issues is that currently I am unable to obtain a gain out of my current circuit design.

I am using a 2N7002 MOSFET in my simulated design
My input signal is 1v/100hz with a 12v power supply.

What could be the issue here?

My current desgin
[image: Circuit design]

Red is my input signal

Green is my output
[image: Input and Output]

Comment: where are you measuring the output?

Comment: How did you derive the biasing conditions? What DC voltage do you see on gate, drain and source? Is that within theFET's  linear region?

Answer (score 1):

With the 2 MΩ and 3.9 MΩ input resistors, the time taken for the bias to set-up correctly on the gate will be approximately the parallel combination of those resistors multiplied by the input capacitance: -

$$\text{(2 MΩ || 3.9 MΩ) x 10 μF} = \text{12.9 seconds}$$

You are only running your simulation for 100 ms so you will never reach the point when the transistor starts to operate correctly. I believe LTSpice can be initialized with the capacitor pre-charged to the appropriate value (7.93 volts). You might want to do that.

Alternatively, try reducing the input capacitor to around 33 nF and watch the MOSFET spring into action a lot quicker.

Comment: That helps a lot thank you

Comment: @AdamCave - [how to formally accept an answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKrn6.png).